# Why std::shared_ptr destruct twice when used std::static_pointer_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

my code is as below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct A {
    A() { cout << "c"; }
    ~A() { cout << "d"; }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<void> a = make_shared<vector<A>>(3);
    auto b = static_pointer_cast<vector<A>>(a);
    b->push_back(A{});
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
ccccdddddddd
```

which indicates that the destructor is called **twice**. Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: When "instrumenting" member functions, print the value of `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to fix. The destructor is not being called twice per object. Rather, you are not tracking all of the constructors. Add tracking to the copy and move constructors, as in

```
struct A {
    A() { cout << "c"; }
    A(const A &) { cout << "C"; }
    A(A &&) { cout << "M"; }
    ~A() { cout << "d"; }
};
```

With this change, your output should be

```
ccccMCCCdddddddd
```

indicating 8 constructor calls and 8 destructor calls.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor calls is the result of `b->push_back(A{});` and not of the `static_pointer_cast`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct A {
    A() { cout << "c"; }
    ~A() { cout << "d"; }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<void> a = make_shared<vector<A>>(3);
    auto b = static_pointer_cast<vector<A>>(a);

    return 0;
}
```

shows `cccddd`.

The reason for the additional destructor calls is, because a vector might need to increase its capacity on a `push_back` and when this is done it might need to move/copy the existing elements to a new location, and due to that delete the old elements. So the additional destructors that you see are the result of this.

In your case the copy/move constructs have been created by default. If you manually define them and add logging to it, you can see that they match up.

```
struct A {
    A() { cout << "c"; }
    A(const A&)  { cout << "C"; };
    A(A&&)  { cout << "M"; };
    ~A() { cout << "d"; }
};
```

The only way to prevent it is to create the vector with a capacity that is large enough to hold all elements that you want to save in it.

Comment: when re-allocate vector space to increase its capacity, why ctor is not called and dtor is called?

Comment: @XiaodongLiu because when moving the copy or move constructor is called. These are (if possible) created by default if you don't define them yourself.